# JS: Extract text from a string without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, string, text

I have this string:

```
var string = '<article><img alt="Ice-cream" src=http://placehold.it/300x300g"><div style="float: right; width: 50px;"><p>Lorem Ipsum </p></div></article>';
```

and I am trying to extract the text out of it as such:

```
var $str = $(string).text();
console.log($str)
```

but since I am concerned about performance due to a huge amount of strings with big text, I would want to go natively.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the Browser do the sanitation and use this trick:

```
var str= '<article><img alt="Ice-cream" src=http://placehold.it/300x300g">'+
'<divstyle="float: right; width: 50px;"><p>Lorem Ipsum </p></div></article>';

var dummyNode = document.createElement('div'),
    resultText = '';

dummyNode.innerHTML = str;
resultText = dummyNode.innerText || dummyNode.textContent;
```

This creates a dummy DOM element and sets its HTML content to the input string.
Now the only text can be got by simply calling the DOM property `innerText` or `textContent`.

This is also more safe and robust as Browser has already written better algorithms to get these values.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make global search to find any characters any no. of time between `<` and `>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str='<article><img alt="Ice-cream" src=http://placehold.it/300x300g"><div style="float: right; width: 50px;"><p>Lorem Ipsum </p></div></article>';
var patt=/\<.*?\>/g;

var result = str.replace(patt, "");
console.log(result);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to get text from string that contains `HTML` tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var regex = "/<(.|\n)*?>/";
    var string = '<article><img alt="Ice-cream" src=http://placehold.it/300x300g"><div style="float: right; width: 50px;"><p>Lorem Ipsum </p></div></article>';
    var result = string .replace(regex, "");
    alert(result); // result should be "Lorem Ipsum "

</script>
```

This way you strip all HTML tags with empty string.