# Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, string, text, extract

I am trying to get the inner text of HTML string, using a JS function(the string is passed as an argument). Here is the code:

```js
function extractContent(value) {
  var content_holder = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (value.charAt(i) === '>') {
      continue;
      while (value.charAt(i) != '<') {
        content_holder += value.charAt(i);
      }
    }

  }
  console.log(content_holder);
}

extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>");
```

The problem is that nothing gets printed on the `console(*content_holder* stays empty)`. I think the problem is caused by the `===` operator.

Comment: Your `while` loop is never reached due to the `continue` instruction.

Comment: Try tracing through your code with a "debugger"--did you do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: Extract text from a string without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776680/js-extract-text-from-a-string-without-jquery)

Comment: also similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585029/parse-an-html-string-with-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the pure text without HTML element by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743912/get-the-pure-text-without-html-element-by-javascript)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Create an element, store the HTML in it, and get its **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**:

```js
function extractContent(s) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = s;
  return span.textContent || span.innerText;
};
    
alert(extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>"));
```

---

Here's a version that allows you to have spaces between nodes, although you'd probably want that for block-level elements only:

```js
function extractContent(s, space) {
  var span= document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML= s;
  if(space) {
    var children= span.querySelectorAll('*');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < children.length ; i++) {
      if(children[i].textContent)
        children[i].textContent+= ' ';
      else
        children[i].innerText+= ' ';
    }
  }
  return [span.textContent || span.innerText].toString().replace(/ +/g,' ');
};
    
console.log(extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>.  Nice to <em>see</em><strong><em>you!</em></strong>"));

console.log(extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>.  Nice to <em>see</em><strong><em>you!</em></strong>",true));
```

Comment: Outputs `HelloW3C` - really what OP wanted? Not `Hello W3C`?

Comment: No, white spaces are not required :) Sorry for not mentioning it!

Comment: Added a version that can add spaces between nodes.

Comment: fyi, the part about adding spaces does not work properly for all types of nested nodes: `extractContent("<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>", true)` produces `"foobar "`

Comment: @Xerillio, good point.  It would take more code to differentiate block-level from inline elements, especially considering that CSS could change block-level to inline and vice-versa.

Comment: WARNING: this is subject to XSS attacks. Only assign to innerHTML if you know and control the parameter's contents to reasonable degree.

Comment: I tried using this method in a web-extension - got `Unsafe assignment to innerHTML` error

Comment: @Gangula, you should use DOMParser, which wasn't widely available when I posted this in 2015.

Answer (score 77):

One line (more precisely, one statement) version:

```
function extractContent(html) {
    return new DOMParser()
        .parseFromString(html, "text/html")
        .documentElement.textContent;
}
```

Comment: nice answer +1, but what is the difference between your answer and `Rick Hitchcock` answer

Comment: @shariqueansari, `DOMParser` is "experimental technology" but likely to be  added to the spec.  Its HTML support works in IE10+.  My original answer worked in IE9+, but I've now updated it to support IE8.

Comment: DOMParser now has wide support, see https://caniuse.com/#search=domparser

Comment: hoped this would work on nodejs but it doesnt. ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2plaintext

Comment: Can We use this method for extract some contents by id like: document.getElementById ?

Answer (score 41):

[textContext](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is a very good technique for achieving desired results but sometimes we don't want to load DOM. So simple workaround will be following regular expression:

```
let htmlString = "<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>"
let plainText = htmlString.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```

Comment: I know this is a very old comment, but could you please explain the meaning of the expression /<[^>]+>/g ? I'm having trouble understanding what each individual character means.

Comment: @Kelly The symbols you are referring to are a *regular expression*. It's kind of like a mini-programming language for parsing text. Here's a link to where you can learn more about each symbol: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: It essentially says to find and remove each *<* that has stuff that is not a *>* between it and a *>*.

Comment: most helpful, regex, one of the best tool/mini-language for coders.

Comment: Different technique for different cases, and this is the right approach for my case, Telegram's bot development that require no innerHTML or something that required in web development.

Answer (score 8):

use this regax for remove html tags and store only the inner text in html

it shows the HelloW3c only check it

```
var content_holder = value.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

Comment: please give me a reason please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: If you are going to use regexp, then a simpler version would be `/<[\s\S]*?>/`, or `/<[^]*?>/`. Your `m` flag accomplishes nothing; it relates to the behavior of `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function extractContent(value){
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        div.innerHTML=value;
        var text= div.textContent;            
        return text;
}
window.onload=function()
{
   alert(extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>"));
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you test this? It fails to extract "W3C" as it should.

Comment: Please try your solution with the string `Hello, <p>Buggy<i>World</i></p>`.

Answer (score 2):

## For Node.js

This will use the `jsdom` library, since node.js doesn't have dom features as in browser.

```
import * as jsdom from "jsdom";

const html = "<h1>Testing<h1>";
const text = new jsdom.JSDOM(html).window.document.textContent;

console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily write it out to a block level element that is positioned off the page .. some thing like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="tmp" style="position:absolute;top:-400px;left:-400px;">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function extractContent(value){
        var div=document.getElementById('tmp');
        div.innerHTML=value;
        console.log(div.children[0].innerHTML);//console out p
}

extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>");
</script>
```

Comment: Right approach, but you don't need an element in the DOM to do this. Just create an element with `var div = document.createElement('div')` and proceed from there.

Comment: Also, this will fail with nested HTML elements, such as `<p>Hello<i>Bob</i></p><a>...</a>`. It will retain the markup inside the `p` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match()` function to bring out ***HTML tags***

```js
const text = `<div>Hello World</div>`;
console.log(text.match(/<[^>]*?>/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Rick Hitchcock answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28899585/1705922) AND [KevBot's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59144571), this is how I found the best way to do it :

```
function getTextLoop(element: HTMLElement | ChildNode) {
  const texts = [];
  Array.from(element.childNodes).forEach((node) => {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
      texts.push(node.textContent.trim());
    } else {
      texts.push(...getTextLoop(node));
    }
  });
  return texts;
}

function innerText(element: HTMLElement) {
  return getTextLoop(element).join(" ");
}

export function extractContent(s, space) {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = s;
  if (space) {
    span.innerHTML = innerText(span);
  }
  return [span.textContent || span.innerText].toString().replace(/ +/g, " ");
}
```

Example :

```
extractContent("<div>foo<div>bar</div></div>", true); // foo bar
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, in jQuery we can add comma seperated tags.

```
var readableText = [];
$("p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").each(function(){ 
     readableText.push( $(this).text().trim() );
})
console.log( readableText.join(' ') );
```

Answer (score -2):

you need array to hold values

```
  function extractContent(value) {
var content_holder = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
    if(value.charAt(i) === '>') {
        continue;
        while(value.charAt(i) != '<') {
            content_holder.push(value.charAt(i));
            console.log(content_holder[i]);
        }
    }
}
}extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>");
```

Comment: You don't **need** an array, if you want the results to be a string but having an array will allow the user to access each result/value.

Comment: You haven't fixed the basic logic error in the OP code. Did you test this?

Comment: I'm going to guess "**not**"