# HTML to (Text) String (not to view) in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string

There are a lot of ways to present a html in angular.

fi use `$sce.trustAsHtml(myHtmlVariable)`

However, what i want to create is a such a thing:

```
myStringVariable = someFunction(myHtmlVariable)
```

Then i will be able to do some operations on my string, without html elements and attributes but ***just with texts***. Is there such a function?

Comment: You can use in directive compile phase.

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: `compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {` here tElement is what you're trying to with myHtmlVariable

Comment: how can i use that in this case?

Comment: Angular doesn't automatically trust HTML. You have to specifically make it trust HTML. The value in the DOM without trusting it will be a string form. Within the actual JS code, it will always be a string form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understood, there is no directly method in angular to transform html to text.

Just using DOMParser (which is working in IE10+), the following function ([from another so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript)) does what i needed:

```
function extractContent(html) {
    return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(html, "text/html") . 
        documentElement . textContent;
}
```