# Get text from HTML with appropriate whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

It is easy to extract the text from HTML using the jQuery [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method...

```
$("<p>This <b>That</b> Other</p>").text() == "This That Other"
```

But if there is no whitespace between the words/elements, then text becomes concatenated...

```
$("<p>This <b>That</b><br/>Other</p>").text() == "This ThatOther"
Desired: "This That Other"

$("<div><h1>Title</h1><p>Text</p></div>").text() == "TitleText"
Desired: "Title Text"
```

Is there any way to get all the text from the HTML (either using `.text()` or other methods) which would mean that the above examples would come out as desired?

Comment: Do you want a minimum of one space between each element?

Comment: @Shawn - there just needs to be some whitespace... the amount is irrelevant

Comment: What if you format your HTML with an IDE formatter? Or you could read up the HTML code as string, then use a HTML formatter library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can traverse the DOM tree looking for a node with a nodeType of `3` (text node). When you find one, add it to an array. If you find a non-text node, you can pass it back into the function to keep looking.

```js
function innerText(element) {
  function getTextLoop(element) {
    const texts = [];
    Array.from(element.childNodes).forEach(node => {
      if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        texts.push(node.textContent.trim());
      } else {
        texts.push(...getTextLoop(node));
      }
    });
    return texts;
  }
  return getTextLoop(element).join(' ');
}

/* EXAMPLES */
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<p>This <b>That</b><br/>Other</p>`;
console.log(innerText(div));

const div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.innerHTML = `<div><h1>Title</h1><p>Text</p></div>`;
console.log(innerText(div2));
```

Comment: We have a winner... that's exactly what I needed. Was in the middle of trying to write something similar, but you got there faster with a much nicer bit of code. Thanks

Comment: excellent code!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just worried about br tags, you can replace them with a text node.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector("#text")
var clone = elem.cloneNode(true)
clone.querySelectorAll("br").forEach( function (br) {
  var space = document.createTextNode(' ')
  br.replaceWith(space)
})
var cleanedText = clone.textContent.trim().replace(/\s+/,' ');
console.log(cleanedText)
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <p>This <b>That</br>Other</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not just `<br/>` tags... it's anything where elements are "joined"... such as the extra example I added: `<h1>Title</h1><p>Text</p>`. Sarvesh has got me thinking recursion over children is potentially the way to go

Comment: basic tree walker