# JavaScript Split String Containing HTML On Each Tag

Tags: javascript, html

So I have the below string in which I am trying to parse.

```
var text = '<div class="class" style="color:#666;font-size:12px"><strong style="font-size:12px;color:#123;font-weight:bold;">XXXXXXX</strong><br /><span>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</span></div><div class="classL" style="color:#456;text-align:right;"><a style="color:#789" href="./abc/?id=1">ZZZZZZZ</a></div>'
```

I am thinking that it would need to be split out as it would be written like the so:

```
<div class="class" style="color:#666;font-size:12px">
<strong style="font-size:12px;color:#123;font-weight:bold;">XXXXXXX</strong>
<br />
<span>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</span>
</div>
<div class="classL" style="color:#456;text-align:right;">
<a style="color:#789" href="./abc/?id=1">ZZZZZZZ</a>
</div>
```

And then each line would need to close off its tags so its complete:

```
<div class="class" style="color:#666;font-size:12px"></div>
<strong style="font-size:12px;color:#123;font-weight:bold;">XXXXXXX</strong>
<br />
<span>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</span>
<div class="classL" style="color:#456;text-align:right;"></div>
<a style="color:#789" href="./abc/?id=1">ZZZZZZZ</a>
```

Then finally I would like to get the text of each line using something like the below:

```
jQuery(text[i]).text();
```

To end up with this:

```
XXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
ZZZZZZZ
```

Also if its possible to keep the hyperlink `./abc/?id=1` that would be nice too.

**Attempts**

Initially I tried doing the following but realized that even though I could add the piece that I used to "split" on back to the string, I could not end up with each line being syntactically correct HTML which meant I could not use the jQuery select text function.

```
// Split Text Only
var textArraySplit = name.split(">");
var textArray = new Array();
for(var j = 0; j < textArraySplit.length-1; j++) {
  textArray.push(textArraySplit[j] + ">");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code.

```js
var text = '<div class="class" style="color:#666;font-size:12px"><strong style="font-size:12px;color:#123;font-weight:bold;">XXXXXXX</strong><br /><span>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</span></div><div class="classL" style="color:#456;text-align:right;"><a style="color:#789" href="./abc/?id=1">ZZZZZZZ</a></div>'

let parser = new DOMParser()
let _document = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html")

let _body = _document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

let rec = (children) => {
  for (let i=0; i<children.length ; i++) {
    let child = children[i]
    if (child.children.length) {
      rec(child.children)
    }
    else if(child.innerText.length > 0) {
    console.log(child.innerText)
    }
  }
}

rec(_body.children)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to create a DOM element and extract the text. See this answer: [Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript/28899585)