# Get the text without the HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tags

I am returning posts from Wordpress api, currently getting an array with posts inside. I can get a string returned but it includes HTML tags. I have used textContent and innerText but don't seem to be working.

I am currently returning `<p> info: 111,<br /> key: fdfd ,<br /> city: ,<br /> suburb: ,<br /> job:  </p>`

What would be the best way top just return the content without the `<p>` and `<br>`?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert the string into an HTML page and then target the "p" element and extract its text.  Something like:

```
var p = "<p> info: 111,<br /> key: fdfd ,<br /> city: ,<br /> suburb: ,<br /> job:  </p>"
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(p, 'text/html');
console.log(htmlDoc.body.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is more of a warning for another common way.**

A common alternative to `DOMParser()`, mentioned by ATD, is to create an element, add it as `innerHTML` and fetch it using `textContent`.

```js
let tParser = document.createElement('div');
tParser.innerHTML = "<p> info: 111,<br /> key: fdfd ,<br /> city: ,<br /> suburb: ,<br /> job:  </p>";
console.log(tParser.textContent)
```

Yet be aware of the risks implied using `innerHTML`. Everything gets interpreted as HTML and executed from your site. Which means, do **not** add it to the DOM or better, try to avoid it entirely.

Furthermore MDN mentions the following:

> If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review,
> using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected.
> For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit
> the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated
> review process.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score -1):

Your question is already answered:

```js
function extractContent(s) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = s;
  return span.textContent || span.innerText;
};
    
alert(extractContent("<p>Hello</p><a href='http://w3c.org'>W3C</a>"));
```

original question:
[Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Should flag it as duplicate instead. Also `innerHTML` is not a recommended way of doing it, as Lain also described.