# Replace all tags and space

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to replace the below string

```
<span class="test">select&nbsp;</span><span class="click">*&nbsp;</span><span class="test">from&nbsp;</span><span class="click">table&nbsp;</span>
```

to `select * from table`. I have been struggling with this for a while now so hopefully someone can help me out.

I am able to replace the `&nbsp` and `</span>`, but not able to remove the remaining parts.

```js
string = `<span class="test">select&nbsp;</span><span class="click">*&nbsp;</span><span class="test">from&nbsp;</span><span class="click">table&nbsp;</span>`;
string = string.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"").replace(/<\/span\s*\/?>/gi, ' ');
  // .replace("<span class=\"([^\"]+)\"", "g");
console.log(string);
```

Please help me.

Comment: Well, that string looks an awfully lot like HTML. Maybe parse it using an HTML parser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the DOM

```js
const str = '<span class="test">select&nbsp;</span><span class="click">*&nbsp;</span><span class="test">from&nbsp;</span><span class="click">table&nbsp;</span>';

const span = document.createElement('span');
span.innerHTML = str;
console.log(span.innerText);

// "select * from table "
```

and if you want to use regexp

```
s.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
```

Here I'm removing any `<` followed by 1 or more `not(>)` and a `>` and the end

Comment: Thanks.. used regexp method and its  replaced all unwanted codes from the string. Very simple and one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
string = `<span class="test">select&nbsp;</span><span class="click">*&nbsp;</span><span class="test">from&nbsp;</span><span class="click">table&nbsp;</span>`;


string = string
.replace(/<span class=\"\S+\">/gi, '')
.replace(/<\/span>/gi, '')
.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ')
;
  
console.log(string);
```

Edit: As [Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille) suggested, there is a better regex for *spans*.

```js
string = `<span class="test">select&nbsp;</span><span class="click">*&nbsp;</span><span class="test">from&nbsp;</span><span class="click">table&nbsp;</span>`;


string = string
.replace(/<\/?span.*?>/g,'')
.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, ' ')
;
  
console.log(string);
```

Comment: All the spans can go away with one regex `/<\/?span.*?>/g`