# Extract String In-between Div Tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have a string that contains HTML code. Part of this code contains the preheader of an email. How would I extract the text in-between `<div class="preheader" style="font-size: 1px; display: none !important;">` and closing `</div>`? Assume the opening and closing divs will always remain the same, only the content in-between changes.

```
some html preceding...
<div class="preheader" style="font-size: 1px; display: none !important;">Email preheader content</div>
some html following...
```

Comment: Parse the HTML and use DOM methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the text out of HTML string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899298/extract-the-text-out-of-html-string-using-javascript)

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("preheader")[0].innerText

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string of html, you can turn it into a DocumentFragment which is just like a DOM. Then in this DOM you can select the element  that you want to get the content of.

Here is an example:

```
const html = "your html code here";

const dom = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(html);
// create DocumentFragment

const preheader = dom.querySelector(".preheader"); // Select the element that contains the content

const content = preheader.textContent; // Extract the content
```