# How to remove New Line Breaks from Knockout html binding?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, foreach

So currently I have a foreach loop that pulls in a list of messages, like a message center, where it shows the date/computed short subject/computed short message/status. So when it pulls in the short message I have it displayed as HTML since it's a message from an HTML Editor. But when it displays it displays with all the spaces and whatever else is in the message until it hits 25 characters.

How would I either remove the newline breaks from the html message upon adding it to the foreach loop? Or if I switched it over to the knockout text binding, remove the html characters and replace with a space?

Knockout:

```
 self.ShortSubject = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Subject().length < 20) {
            return self.Subject();
        }
        else {
            return self.Subject().substring(0, 20) + '...';
        }
    });

    self.ShortMessage = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Message().length < 50) {
            return self.Message();
        }
        else {
            return self.Message().substring(0, 50) + '...';
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered text-center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-success">
                                    <th width="15%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortMessageType" style="cursor: pointer">Message Type </th>
                                    <th width="25%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortSubject" style="cursor: pointer">Subject </th>
                                    <th width="40%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: sortMessage" style="cursor: pointer">Message </th>
                                    <th width="20%" class="table-title" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { sortDateCreated( $data, event ) }" style="cursor: pointer">Date Created </th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: VisibleTemplates">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.MessageType"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.ShortSubject"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.ShortMessage"></td>
                                    <td class="mailbox-subject" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.selectTemplate( $data, event ) }, text: $data.DateTime"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Show us what your data looks like, and what your code looks like.

Comment: Added my code to my original post

Comment: And a sample of the problem data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with truncating HTML is that you might have unclosed tags in it which could destroy the formatting of your page. So you probably want to just extract the text, which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776680/js-extract-text-from-a-string-without-jquery#answer-18780568) tells you how to do.

If you feel confident that your table cells won't break with the HTML you're going to get, you can set the `display`style for everything inside a cell to `inline`.

```css
.short-message * {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="short-message"><h1>Hi there</h1>
<div>Some Text</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
```